# Is it possible to hide QSA variables when using mod rewirite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My rule in the htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^brands/([^/.]+)/?$ browse-brand.php?brand=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Turns the midly ugly 
**www.mysite.com/brands.php?brand=$brandName**
into a more attractive
**www.mysite.com/brands/brandName/**

Each brand page is used to display hundreds of products relating to that brand so is split in to pages and can be filtered to show 20/50/100 products or order by price/bestsellers etc

So my newly made 'pretty urls' become ugly again when attaching the sorting and ordering variables using QSA, such as:

**www.mysite.com/brands/brandName/product_show=20&product_sort=sortpricedesc&page=2**

Obviously the pages won't perform without these extra variables. I suppose it's possible to change my RewriteRule to include these, like so:

**www.mysite.com/brands/brandName/20/sortpricedesc/2/**

but that's still a bit ugly.

Is there a way to hide these variables from displaying in the URL bar? How do you deal with product catalogues with multiple pages?

Comment: After more research I think I'm actually asking the impossible. The extra variables are required and can't be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^brands/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ browse-brand.php?brand=$1&product_show=$2&product_sort=$3&page=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^brands/([^/.]+)/?$ browse-brand.php?brand=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The final page is the same `browse-brand.php`with new variables. But you also can change the name in this case.